# Obtener horas, minutos y segundos desde la fecha de nacimiento

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

No sé si el formato de este script es correcto o no. Me gustaría saber si voy por buen camino y si me podríais ayudar en dos parámetros que me faltan y no consigo sacar.

Enunciado del ejercicio: Pregunte al usuario fecha de nacimiento, a partir de ella dígale el número de segundos,
minutos y horas que ha vivido.

Código que llevo hecho hasta ahora:

```
!/bin/bash 

read -p "Introduce tu fecha de nacimiento (formato: añomesdia) : " fecha

DIAS=$(( ($(date --date $fecha +%s) - $(date +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))
HORAS=$(( ($(date --date $fecha +%s) - $(date +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))

echo "Dias: $DIAS"
echo "Horas: $HORAS"
echo "Minutos: $MINUTOS"
```

No soy capaz de sacar las horas de diferencia que hay entre la fecha que introduzco y la fecha actual, tampoco soy capaz de sacar los minutos.

Imagino que habrá un formato para hacerlo pero no lo encuentro.

Answer (score 2):

Como hace la [solución de track3r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/137749/83), la clave aquí está en convertir la fecha de hoy y la del día de nacimiento en unix timestap. Esto es, en el número de segundos que han pasado desde el 1 de enero de 1970, que viene a ser como el Big Bang unixero.

Por ello, lo ideal sería primero normalizar la fecha recibida, luego convertir ambas a unix timestamp, sustraer una de la otra y finalmente hacer el cálculo:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Introduce tu fecha de nacimiento (formato: añomesdia) : " fecha
hoy=$(date)

secs_hasta_fecha=$(date -d"$fecha" "+%s")  # esta fecha se da en la hora 00:00:00
secs_hasta_hoy=$(date -d"$hoy" "+%s")

# Calcula la diferencia en segundos entre las dos fechas dadas
dif=$((secs_hasta_hoy - secs_hasta_fecha))

# Calcula la diferencia en horas, minutos y segundos
horas=$((dif / 3600))
mins=$(( (dif - horas*3600) / 60))
segs=$((dif - horas*3600 - mins*60))

# Imprime el resultado
printf "la dif entre %s y hoy %s es de %d horas, %d minutos y %d segundos\n" "$fecha" "$hoy" "$horas" "$mins" "$segs"
```

---

De tu código, no puedo dejar de comentar un par de cosas:

```
!/bin/bash   # <--- ¡falta # al principio!

# esto es correcto
read -p "Introduce tu fecha de nacimiento (formato: añomesdia) : " fecha
```

Probablemente en lugar de calcular la fecha cada vez, es mejor guardarla en una variable y luego operar a partir de allí:

```
DIAS=$(( ($(date --date $fecha +%s) - $(date +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))
HORAS=$(( ($(date --date $fecha +%s) - $(date +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))
```

Además de que las variables siempre se recomienda que estén en minúsculas, para que no colisionen con las variables de entorno, que por convención se escriben en mayúsculas.

```
echo "Dias: $DIAS"
echo "Horas: $HORAS"
echo "Minutos: $MINUTOS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Fuente: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317139/date-difference-calculation/317145#317145

```
Value1='2016-10-13 14:19:23'
Value2='2016-10-18 10:34:58'
D1=$(date -d "$Value1" '+%s'); D2=$(date -d "$Value2" '+%s')
echo "$(((D2-D1)/86400)):$(date -u -d@$((D2-D1)) +%H:%M)"
```

Sará la salida:

```
4:20:15
```

Comment: La cosa es que tengo que darle solo una variable en este caso $fecha y que a raiz de eso me de Dias, horas y minutos sin tener que pedirle mas valores y eso es lo que no soy capaz de sacar

Comment: Value2 puedes definirlo como la fecha actual, no hay problema. En cualquier caso, en el enlace de la fuente tienes más métodos.